# Sender address rejected: Domain not found

Tags: google-app-engine, email, smtp, gmail

I'm getting the error below when sending mail via smtp through google apps mail. Can anyone see why I get this error? As far as I can tell my domain exists!

```
THIS IS A WARNING MESSAGE ONLY.

YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE.

Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:

     a.kozikowski@tutek.pl

Message will be retried for 2 more day(s)

Technical details of temporary failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain tutek.pl by mx.maxus.pl. [213.241.89.166].

The error that the other server returned was:
450 4.1.8 <aquarius@aquariusprams.co.uk>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found
```

Comment: Given that you cross-posted this to Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/questions/477021/email-bounces-sender-address-rejected-domain-not-found , I'm going to close this variant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this error means that the recipient mail server can not resolve the MX (and A) records of `aquariusprams.co.uk`. It works fine here, so its probably a generic dns problem on the recipient side or a routing issue between the recipient and your nameservers ns1.console-covers.com / ns2.console-covers.com.